# How to write a _REQUEST loop?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Here's what I'm doing now in php

```
$layout_type = $_REQUEST['layout_type'];
$aside_location = $_REQUEST['aside_location'];
$aside_style = $_REQUEST['aside_style'];
$nav_bg = $_REQUEST['nav_bg'];
$nav_bg_hover = $_REQUEST['nav_bg_hover'];
$nav_text_color = $_REQUEST['nav_text_color'];
```

There has to be a function that writes it for me with the same name?

Here's my ajax call

```
function generate_clicked()
{
    var  formData = $("#form").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url : "process.php",
        type: "POST",
        data : formData,
        }).done(function ( data ) {
        try{
            $('#preview').val(data.css);
            }
        catch(err)
        {
            console.log(err);
        }
        document.getElementById("my_iframe").src = data.live_preview_html_page;
    });
}
```

Comment: why not use them directly from `$_REQUEST`?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
foreach ($_REQUEST as $Key => $Value) {
  ${$Key} = $Value;
  }
```

However I advise against it from severe security implications. To make it secure, I'd recommend first checking the value against an array (white-listing it):

```
// Complete yourself...
$ValidValues= array("layout_type", "aside_location");

foreach ($_REQUEST as $Key => $Value) {
  if (in_array($Key, $ValidValues)) {
    ${$Key} = $Value;
    }
  else {
    throw new Exception("Security violation. Requesting non-existing variable " . $Key);
    }
  }
```

Although you ought to ask yourself why you need this, since your request makes no sense. **Arrays are for storing this kind of data**, not many individual variables, **and you already have that in your $_REQUEST**. So please, see down there in your code if you can just use the data straight forward, or provide some more code/context so we can help you further with your problem.

Comment: I should just write each line? I'm doing around 50 of theses.

Comment: See the updated answer. You can always store the possible values in an array and check against it.

Comment: dynamically futzing with the symbol table makes it incredibly difficult to tell where variables come from, and that's hard enough as is

Comment: You don't need the loop for that, `array_intersect_key($_POST, array_flip($ValidValues))` would be sufficient for whitelisting.

Comment: I concentrated on answering the question and forgot completely about providing an useful answer. I agree, @Eevee

Comment: I'm submitting a form, using the value of that form to create a theme, and using those values for math and if/else statements

Comment: Are you using ALL of the values for math and if/else? You only need to put into specific, separated variables the ones that are used more than once/twice, not all of them.

Comment: For example, I see you've got a `$_REQUEST['nav_bg'];`. That should be probably straight into your css file, no need to pass it to an aditional variable. As a sidenote: [use `$_POST` instead of `$_REQUEST` for fetching your data](http://forums.devnetwork.net/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=89534).

Answer (score 0):

Current versions of PHP provide the [`extract()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) function to do what you want, although it's ***not advised*** to use it on `$_REQUEST` since any user can alter your form client-side and submit unexpected variables to your PHP script.

If you choose to use this function, it's **strongly recommended** that you use the `EXTR_SKIP` flag or provide a prefix to prevent existing variables from being unexpectedly altered.

```
extract($_REQUEST, EXTR_SKIP); 
// the EXTR_SKIP flag will prevent variables from being overwritten
// or:
extract($_REQUEST, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, 'prefix_'); 
// prepend all your new variable names for safety
```

That said, the *safest* way by far is to explicitly set each variable as you're doing now. That way, you know exactly what variables are being set when, and security risks are minimized.

Comment: I know, but it wasn't me who downvoted... and don't upvote because the security hole is still there

Comment: There's really no way to do what OP wants without opening a security hole, which is why I mentioned that there is one.

Comment: then the correct answer is "don't do this".  why help someone write insecure software just because e asked?

Comment: @Eevee No, the *good* answer is "Don't do this." There is a difference. The answer I've provided answers the question as written, and the fact that it's inadvisable has been mentioned and emphasized.